# Unable to rename table due to metadata lock

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to rename a table but it always just hangs with a `Waiting for table metadata lock`. Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
start transaction;
RENAME TABLE `main_territorypricing` TO `main_territorypricing2`;
RENAME TABLE `main_territorypricing1` TO `main_territorypricing`;
COMMIT;
```

Yet the first rename statement hangs indefinitely. How would I rename the two tables?

Comment: It seems there were uncommitted transactions that wouldn't show up in `show processlist` and couldn't be killed by killing their thread. What was required to 'free up' the table was a database restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `RENAME TABLE` will terminate the transaction.

You can do both renames in a single, atomic, statement (no transaction):

```
RENAME TABLE `main_territorypricing`  TO `main_territorypricing2`,
             `main_territorypricing1` TO `main_territorypricing`;
```

It will have to wait for any other connections that are busy with any of the tables; make sure you don't have some connection not letting go.